# When SSHD process started using systemctl process is terminated by systemd seconds later

Tags: systemd, sshd

When I start the sshd process using systemctl the process starts successfully but is terminated ~5 seconds later. When I run the ExecStart command on the command line ssh runs without any issues.

Can anyone tell me why systemd might be sending a sigterm to sshd when started using systemctl?

I'm running SLES12-SP2.

Output of "systemctl status sshd" just after running "systemctl start sshd":

```
● sshd.service - OpenSSH Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-07-09 12:51:10 BST; 2s ago
  Process: 21727 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd-gen-keys-start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 21734 (sshd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 8192)
   CGroup: /system.slice/sshd.service
           └─21734 /usr/sbin/sshd -D -ddd

Jul 09 12:51:10 Duke sshd[21734]: debug1: rexec_argv[2]='-ddd'
Jul 09 12:51:10 Duke sshd[21734]: debug3: oom_adjust_setup
Jul 09 12:51:10 Duke sshd[21734]: debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
Jul 09 12:51:10 Duke sshd[21734]: debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
Jul 09 12:51:10 Duke sshd[21734]: debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Jul 09 12:51:10 Duke sshd[21734]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jul 09 12:51:10 Duke sshd[21734]: debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
Jul 09 12:51:10 Duke sshd[21734]: debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 4 IPV6_V6ONLY
Jul 09 12:51:10 Duke sshd[21734]: debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Jul 09 12:51:10 Duke sshd[21734]: Server listening on :: port 22.
```

Output of "systemctl status sshd" just around 5 seconds later:

```
● sshd.service - OpenSSH Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2017-07-09 12:51:12 BST; 2s ago
  Process: 21734 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D -ddd $SSHD_OPTS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 21727 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd-gen-keys-start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 21734 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 09 12:51:10 Duke sshd[21734]: debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
Jul 09 12:51:10 Duke sshd[21734]: debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Jul 09 12:51:10 Duke sshd[21734]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jul 09 12:51:10 Duke sshd[21734]: debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
Jul 09 12:51:10 Duke sshd[21734]: debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 4 IPV6_V6ONLY
Jul 09 12:51:10 Duke sshd[21734]: debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Jul 09 12:51:10 Duke sshd[21734]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jul 09 12:51:12 Duke systemd[1]: Stopping OpenSSH Daemon...
Jul 09 12:51:12 Duke systemd[1]: Stopped OpenSSH Daemon.
Jul 09 12:51:12 Duke sshd[21734]: Received signal 15; terminating.
```

Contents of /usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenSSH Daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/ssh
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd-gen-keys-start
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D -ddd $SSHD_OPTS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=never

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Note: I changed Restart to never from always so I could see the last messages from sshd. SSHD is terminated in both cases.

Comment: Try disabling selinux?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't anything that literally runs `systemctl stop sshd` or otherwise asks systemd to stop that service?

Comment: @grawity not that I'm aware of.

Comment: You could try checking if anything else is happening before the `Stopping OpenSSH Daemon...` by doing `sudo journalctl -e`.

Answer (score 2):

You added `-ddd` arguments to the `sshd`. Having a look into the manual page, where you find these arguments, you can notice the following:

> `-d`
>
> Debug mode.  The server sends verbose debug output to standard error, and does not put itself in the background.  **The server also will not fork and will only process one connection.** This option is only intended for debugging for the server.  Multiple -d options increase the debugging level.  Maximum is 3.

So this does exactly what is expected.

If you wish to see the debug messages, use the `LogLevel DEBUG3` option in `sshd_config`. It will not affect this behavior, but will log the messages.